I want to create below app design using customPainter in flutter

I want to create appBar like below but i don't have good knowledge of customPainter.
It should be like below design.
I have attached the image
unable to do this using cubic and beizer curve in flutter.
 void paint(Canvas canvas, Size size) {
 final paint = Paint()
      ..color = Colors.red
      ..style = PaintingStyle.fill
      ..strokeWidth = 4.0;
  final path = Path();
  path.moveTo(0, 0);
  path.lineTo(size.width, 0);
  path.lineTo(size.width, size.height);
  path.lineTo(size.width-30, size.height);
  // path.cubicTo(size.width-10, size.height,
  // size.width-60, size.height+20,
  // size.width-60, size.height-10
  // );
  path.relativeCubicTo(size.width-40,
  100,
  size.width-60, 10,
  size.width-60,0
  );
  path.lineTo(0, size.height);
  canvas.drawPath(path, paint);     


Try the following version of ClipPath.

Here's the clipper:
class AppBarClipper extends CustomClipper<Path>{
  @override
  Path getClip(Size size) {
   
   Path path = Path();
   double w = size.width;
   double h = size.height;
   double amountToClip = w /10;
   path.lineTo(w,0);
   path.lineTo(w,h);
   path.lineTo(w - amountToClip , h );
   path.quadraticBezierTo(w-1.25 * amountToClip, h-.5*amountToClip,  w- 1.5 * amountToClip , h -amountToClip / 2);
   path.lineTo(1.5 * amountToClip, h - amountToClip / 2);
   path.quadraticBezierTo(1.25 * amountToClip, h-.5*amountToClip , amountToClip , h);
   path.lineTo(0 , h);
   path.lineTo(0,0);
   return path;
  }

  @override
  bool shouldReclip(covariant CustomClipper<Path> oldClipper) =>true;
}

And here's the widget after applying the clip path:
ClipPath(
   clipper: AppBarClipper(),
   child: Container(
           width: double.infinity,
           height: 80,
           color: Colors.red,
           ),
          ),

For sure, you can tailor that path to justify to your needs.

this is not same as i given the image
there should be rounded corner of beizer curve.
if is there any solution for this please share

@SonuSaini yes , i see. you only need to add more control points (more points on the path) to get the required shape.
